# Pyspark adding an extra row with `.select`

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks, delta-live-tables

I have a pyspark dataframe that I am building out to get the unique values of a column in a table. I have run scripts on this table to update any NULL values in the column in question and have confirmed that there are no NULL values in the table. Here's where things get a weird.

I use `.groupBy` to get a distinct list of the values. I then add a couple of columns using `.withColumn`. If I check the dataframe at this point, I get 9 rows with no NULL values. I then use `.select` to alias certain column names and put them in the correct order (as I then use `.union` to join it with another dataframe and drop duplicates, essentially so I am picking up new values from the source table and can write these new values into my destination table). But when I use `.select`, I suddenly have 10 rows with one row having a null value in the field that comes from the source table. See below:

```
 dfCalls = spark.read.table('foo.bar.my_table') \
                    .groupBy([category_name]) \
                    .count() \
                    .withColumn('categoryName', lit(category_name)) \
                    .withColumn('dimCategoryId', lit(None)) \
                    .select('dimCategoryId', 'categoryName', col(category_name).alias('categoryValue')) \
                    .alias('cm')
```

If I check the results of the above without the `.select` statement, I get 9 rows with no nulls in the `col(category_name)` column but once I add the `.select` clause, I get 10 rows with a `NULL` entry in `col(category_name)`. Why is this happening and how can I fix it (minus adding a `.where` clause to exclude nulls that shouldn't be necessary).

EDIT:
To add to the weirdness, I ran this same code against a few other columns (i.e. different "category_name" values which are essentially columns in `foo.bar.my_table`). For 3 of the values, this code executed as expected (no extra null values). For 2 other values, 1 of them is adding an extra null value (same as above) and the other is adding 2 rows: one null value and one value `== ''` (i.e. empty string). I have checked both columns and neither of them have empty string OR null values in them.

Comment: Took a swing and couldn't reproduce this behavior. It'd help if you provided a create dataframe with the values of foo.bar.my_table.<value of category_name> that reproduces the issue

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't because it's company proprietary data. It doesn't seem specific to the size of the data. Of the 3 columns where this occurs, one has 9 rows, another has more than 10k rows, and the third (that creates both a NULL record and a record with empty string) has about 2.8k rows. The other columns that work fine with this same logic have 15 rows or less. All of the rows are string data.

Comment: I am able to filter out the null and empty string rows if I add a `.where` clause after the `.select` but that shouldn't be necessary because those values don't actually exist in the table.

Comment: You don't necessarily have to share your proprietary data, just try to recreate what you're encountering with fake data. Without being able to easily reproduce your situation, chances are less you'll get an answer to your question.